# Convert Xcursor to PNG

Tags: x11, xorg, cursor, png, xcursor

*Xcursor* is a format for the graphics of the cursor in *X11* (`file` reports `X11 cursor`).

`xcursorgen` allows you to convert PNG files and some metadata to Xcursor files.

How do I convert an Xcursor file to PNG images?

Imagemagick's `convert` unfortunately returns:

> > no decode delegate for this image format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [xcur2png](https://web.archive.org/web/20160604105326/http://cli-apps.org/content/show.php/xcur2png?content=86010).

> Xcur2png takes PNG images from Xcursor-file, and generate config-file
>   which is reusable by xcursorgen. To put it simply, it is converter
>   from X cursor to PNG image.

**Basic usage**

```
xcur2png cursorfile
```

**Converting all cursor files of a theme**

```
find . ! -name '*.*' -type f -exec xcur2png {} \;
```

**Availability**

There are only inofficial packages for [Arch Linux](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xcur2png/) and [Ubuntu (64bit)](https://launchpad.net/~s-lagui/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/2472534) but the app is hassle-free to compile.

*This answer would not have been possible without don_crissti pointing out the tool.*

Comment: The link to xcur2png is dead, but it is a funny page after translated

Comment: xcur2png seems to be available via pacman in Arch Linux now, so it doesn't need to be manually compiled.