# Flip an xcursor in the console

Tags: shell-script, x11, image-manipulation, xcursor

I'm left-handed and I want to be able to correctly flip any arbitrary xcursor theme so that I can use it as a left-handed version.

I’m surprised this isn’t build in.

So a way to flip an xcursor file, say `/usr/share/icons/Bibata-Original-Ice-LH/cursors/pencil`, would help me do that.

I expected it to be as simple as `convert pencil -flop pencil`, but Imagemagick doesn’t support xcursor files, it seems.
And scripting it with Gimp’s script-fu would work, but when using `gimp-file-xmc-save` it expects me to set the hotspot and such, and I can’t find any way to find the old values from the existing file I opened (let alone the hassle of learning Scheme just to do the math to get the flipped values).

Comment: Take a look at very similar queston and answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241364/convert-xcursor-to-png. I also think you should be able to find source PNG and config files for your theme which can be processed with  xcursorgen. You should change those sources with your scripts, if xcur2png would not be available, and create new cursors with xcursorgen.

Comment: This perl script [xcursor-converter](https://github.com/Infinality/xcursor-converter) says it can convert to left-handed.